# JHipster Social Login - make email a mandatory field

Tags: jhipster, spring-social, spring-social-facebook

I just setup the basic JHipster application and set in the FB client ID and secret. However, when I try to login by not sharing the email - I see that it gets redirected to my app with a success. I can handle the no email exception on application.

Instead , I wanted FB to make sure that my email was a mandatory field. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't force Facebook to return an email address for a user.  It may also be null on their end (if the user signed up with a phone number).  You will have to handle it in your application.  This is the same case with Twitter - they simply don't provide the user's email.

> Note, even if you request the email permission it is not guaranteed you will get an email address. For example, if someone signed up for Facebook with a phone number instead of an email address, the email field may be empty.
>
> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/

Like you mentioned, you need to handle it in your application.  You could catch the fact the email is null and prompt the user to enter an email.

Comment: Trying to put a breakpoint and see where to redirect is a nightmare as FB doesnt support localhost. Do i change the /etc/hosts file and do it?

Comment: You can use localhost as a redirect URI.  It should look like `http://localhost:8080/signin/facebook`.  Is that what you are asking?

Comment: I tried putting `http://localhost:8080/` as my redirect URL - it didnt work. To test it - I had to host my app online and test it (I used heroku)

Comment: Please read my last comment.  The URL should look like `http://localhost:8080/signin/facebook` not `http://localhost:8080/`.  If you are hosting on Heroku, you need to use that URL instead of `localhost:8080`